# Inverse function for non-linear regression purpouses

Tags: inverse, regression, inverse-function

---

**The Setting:**

I want to perform a regression onto data of that follows this shape:
\begin{equation}
U(x):=\sum_{i=1}^N\, a_ix^ie^{-b_ix}
\end{equation}
where the $a_i\in \mathbb{R}$ and the $b_i \in (0,\infty)$, where all the data values are (and must be) non-negative.

---

**The Question:**

In order to preform this regression I need to explicitly know the inverse of the map $U$ (so I can linearize the data, perform a linear regression and then return the data to normal).
My question is what is the inverse function of $U$?

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $x\mapsto U(x)$ is non-negative when $x\ge 0$ and is $0$ when $x=0$, and approaches $0$ as $x\to\infty$.  That means that as $x$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$, $U(x)$ starts at $0$ then goes up and comes back down.  Therefore $U$ is not one-to-one, so it does not have an inverse function.

I am inclined to doubt that such a transformation as you suggest would work in this case even if not for the difficulty identified in the paragraph above.

Comment: I'll ask a different question, then on how to regress data of that form...  Thank you for your answer.